# D3 Visualization from example using SVG and Canvas hybrid

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js, visualization

I am learning D3, and finding it quite painful to get a handle on all of the moving pieces. After going over basics and reading sections of a few books, I decided to try and bind my own data to a popular, more complex Mike Bostock example found in the wild ([Facebook IPO](http://www.nytimes.com/interactive/2012/05/17/business/dealbook/how-the-facebook-offering-compares.html)). I figure more often than not, this is similar to the workflow I'll use in real life, rather than coding a viz from scratch.

Here is my current code (http://codepen.io/dharkko/pen/bNOOOo/).

Here are my questions:

- Why isn't any of my Javascript affecting the SVG?
- How can I rescale via transform/translate, both the X and Y axis within the 900 by 500 SVG (or 875 by 480 canvas)?
- Since the Javascript is not affecting the SVG, no data will bind. Why?

I have faith that this might all seem clear to me one day, but my awareness level won't currently allow it.

Lastly, in the few D3s I have done thus far, I settled on a simplified template that went like so:

```html
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script src="d3.js"></script>
    <script>
    function draw(data) {
        "use strict";
        //put your function in here

    }

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <script>
        //call your draw function on your data here
        //d3.json("data/data_file.json", draw);
    </script>
        //put your svg/canvas here
        
</body>
</html>
```

Might this template be helpful here? Thanks

**Updated**: Thanks to @Mark, the issue with formatting the x-axis to a specific date range has been solved by adding these lines:

```
var x = d3.time.scale()
   .range([0, width]);

function randomDate(start, end) {
      return new Date(start.getTime() + Math.random() * (end.getTime() - start.getTime()));
    }

var data = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
  data.push({
    x: randomDate(new Date(1970, 0, 1), new Date(2015, 0, 1)),
    y: Math.random() * 100,
    r: Math.random() * 30,
    c: color(Math.random() * 3)
  });
}

x.domain([new Date(1970, 0, 1), new Date(2015, 0, 1)]);
y.domain([-10, 110]).nice();
```

Comment: Can I recommend you **don't** try to adapt that NYTimes example.  The code in there is minified and therefore very difficult to read.  In addtion, it looks to be using d3.v2, which is outdated at this point.  Finally, I quick look at your codepen, you cut and pasted the SVG that's output by d3 into the HTML window and secondly I can't see where you ever call your `draw` function...

Comment: Thanks for the affirmation.. My takeaway is that my best option is to shut down this specific example and go with a sturdier example. I'm still curious as to how it's done. I have not found similar examples..

Comment: Which piece are you curious about?  It's just a simple scatterplot with varying radius on each circle.  Here's a [quick example](http://plnkr.co/edit/MYSqvqSdDY7XKTJjhh12?p=preview) I just put together.

Comment: Your example does help simplify. I'm still trying to format the x-axis to take dates from 1970 to 2015, and there is some weird stuff going on. Currently, it's accepting a domain range that sets ticks automatically. I'm reading this (https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Time-Scales) with no luck - it is utterly confusing. Axis in particular do not seem intuitive.

Comment: See updated example [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/MYSqvqSdDY7XKTJjhh12?p=preview) with a datetime x axis.